# How would I convert a string into a table in python?

Tags: python

How would I convert a string into a table in python?
Example:

```
s = "hello"
s.TurnIntoTable -> s = ["h","e","l","l","o"]
```

Comment: It's not a table, it is called a list.

Comment: coming from perl?

Comment: sorry guys i'm new to python, my main language is lua

Comment: Lua tables are much the same as Python `dict`s. But where Lua uses tables as its only data structure, Python has specialized data structures: lists, tuples, sets; and explicit classes in place of Lua's roll-your-own approach. An afternoon spent with a Python tutorial might be in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list(s)`

should do what your asking

or maybe

`[list(line) for line in s.splitlines()]`

Answer (score 0):

Simple turn it to a list:

```
s = "hello"
print( list(s) )

#['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).